# How do I reformat and output a javascript string into array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, variables, epoch

Still learning... again sorry if this sounds stupid:

I have 2 variables "timestamps" and "clicks" and a string of numbers:

```
  var myData = {
  "timestamps":[
    1362096000000,1362355200000,1362441600000,1362528000000
  ],
  "clicks":[
    [
      1,2,3,4
    ]
};
```

I'm trying to restructure that into an array in this format:

```
[1362096000000,1],
[1362355200000,2],
[1362441600000,3],
[1362528000000,4],
```

Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/3UsP6/1/

Javascript:

```
var myData = {"timestamps":[1369008000,1369094400,1369180800,],"clicks":[1,2,3,]};
var output = test; 
for (var i = 0, l = myData.timestamps.length; i < l; i++) 
{ 
    output.push([myData.timestamps[i], myData.clicks[i]]);
}
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="javascript:alterText()">
    <a id="test"></a>
</body>
```

I need to output the variable into the body of the page but I can't get it to display. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before anything else, if you are debugging, you are better off using the debugger of the browser (F12 in most browsers). Use `console.log()` to output to the console to see values. Breakpoints would be better since they pause code, and you can inspect values at that moment.

Now, for the mistakes you made:

- Your `output` is `test` which is an `<a>`. You can't do a `push` since that's not an array. What you can do is create an array, fill it with values, and do a `JSON.stringify` to turn it into a string.
- You should use `document.get*` functions, like `document.getElementId()` to refer to DOM elements. Though browsers do expose globals for elements with `id`s, you should avoid that.

[This should fix it](http://jsfiddle.net/3UsP6/4/):

```
function alterText() {
    var myData = {
        "timestamps": [1369008000, 1369094400, 1369180800],
            "clicks": [1, 2, 3]
    };

    var output = [];
    var link = document.getElementById('test');

    for (var i = 0, l = myData.timestamps.length; i < l; i++) {
        output.push([myData.timestamps[i], myData.clicks[i]]);
    }

    // Output to console
    console.log(output);

    // Convert array to text and output to element
    link.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(output);
}
```

Comment: This is awesome!! Thanks so much - so to add a line break, why wouldn't it work to just add "/n" to the output?

Answer (score 0):

A big problem with the jFiddle is you don't include jQuery. When trying to get an element by id, you cannot just reference it by name. Below is a revised version that does output what you want (though not in a nice format or anything).

```
$(function() {
    var myData = {"timestamps":[1369008000,1369094400,1369180800,],"clicks":[1,2,3,]};

    var output = $('#test'); 
    for (var i = 0; i < myData.timestamps.length; i++) { 
        output.append([myData.timestamps[i], myData.clicks[i]]);
    }
});
```

Comment: You do see that the post didn't tag jQuery.

Comment: My mistake, did not notice. Thanks.